# Why is mix() not working with my colors in LESSC?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

My less file piggy-backs on to the end of the Twitter Bootstrap files (so things like `@white` are defined already.  Here is my less code:

```
@columnSortScreen: #99f;
// the color used
@columnSort: mix( @white, @columnSortScreen );
```

When compiled, I get the following error (everything underlined by carets is highlighted):

```
non_object_property_loadError: error evaluating function `mix`: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in /Users/cmv/Sites/...../tablesorter.less:12:14
11 // the color used
12  @columnSort: mix( @white, @columnSortScreen );
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong?  Lessc is version 1.3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same error.

Did some digging and found this:

> The docs for mix are missing the third parameter.
>
> Try:
>
> ```
> @fallback-color: mix(@from-color, @to-color, 50%);
> ```

Note the third parameter. This solved it in my case, does this fix it for you?